# Flutter hive not saving properly

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I have a provider class with the save function to the hive database. When the app is running I am getting the prints that the local and database List is updated. As soon when I make a hot restart on the initial load I am getting all data from data base but when I make a save call List is cleared and I am having just the last saved data.

This is a provider function.

```
void saveDrill(String drillName) {
    String formattedDay = DateFormat.yMd().format(_dateTime);
    String formattedHours = DateFormat.Hms().format(_dateTime);

    List oneDrill = [
      drillName,
      formattedDay,
      formattedHours,
      _parTime,
      _isMagazine,
      _isHostler,
      [..._shootsList]
    ];
    historyDb.historyList.add(oneDrill);
    historyDb.updateHistory();
    _isSave = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Here you have database:

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class HistoryDatabase {
  final _myBox = Hive.box("SETTINGS");

  List historyList = [];

  void loadHistory() {
    historyList = List.from(_myBox.get("history"));
  }

  void updateHistory() {
    _myBox.put("history", historyList);
  }
}
```

And here the init state in the widget.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final provider = Provider.of<DrillProvider>(context, listen: false);
    if (_myBox.get("setting") != null) {
      provider.loadSettings();
    }
    if (_myBox.get("history") != null) {
      historyDb.loadHistory();
      print('database');
      print(_myBox.get('history'));
      print('lokalna');
      print(historyDb.historyList);
    }
  }
```

Any ideas?